# Java - passing ArrayList of interface type

Tags: java, interface, arraylist

I have an interface Damageable as follows

```
public interface Damageable {
    public void handleCollision(float impulse);
}
```

a class which implements this interface, BaseObject

```
public class BaseObject implements Damageable
```

Now in a third class, I have an ArrayList of the type BaseObject

```
public class ObjectManager {    
    public ArrayList<BaseObject> bodies;
```

What I am trying to do is to pass the ArrayList bodies to a method of another class which accepts ArrayList

```
public CollisionManager( ArrayList<Damageable> _bodies) {
        bodies = _bodies;
}
```

Java does not let me do new CollisionManager(bodies) where bodies is of type ArrayList and BaseObject implements Damageable

I have tried casting. Says cannot cast from 
`ArrayList<BaseObject>` to ArrayList
Also tried using `Class<? extends Damageable>` but then I'm unable to call methods declared in the interface Damageable. How can I pass the ArrayList?

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965035/why-cant-a-method-take-a-collectionsubclass-when-the-methods-signature-is-de

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You have to be explicit with your generics.  Therefore, you have to inform the compiler that your generic type doesn't *have* to be a `Damagable` per se, rather it can *extend* `Damagable`:

```
public CollisionManager(ArrayList<? extends Damagable> bodies) {
```

---

By the way, notice that I changed your variable to `bodies` rather than `_bodies`.  Underscores are not part of the standard Java coding conventions.

---

<sup>Edit in response to the OP's comments</sup>

Let's say that, instead of an interface, you had a *concrete* class called `Damagable`.  Telling the compiler `<? extends Damagable>` says that it doesn't have to be an instance of `Damagable`.  It's *okay* that the type *extend* `Damagable`.  Otherwise, the compiler assumes that you have a `Damagable` ***exactly***.

It doesn't make as much sense when you think of `Damagable` as an interface, since there is not case where you would have an instance of `Damagable`.  But they work in essentially the same way.

You have to remember that you're working with Java *types*, not classes.  Java's type syntax and structure is less robust than it's class structure.  There is no concept of `implements` when it comes to types.

---

<sup>Last round of edits</sup>

Finally, I should note that it's generally better to use an interface for method/constructor parameters and method return types.  This allows you and those that use your methods to use whatever implementation you please, and allows you to change your implementation as you please.

So with those revisions, you would have:

```
public CollisionManager(List<? extends Damagable> bodies) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the ArrayList HAS to implement Damageable since I am using methods of that interface.

Comment: `? extends Damagable` *means* `implements Damagable` in Java generic-speak.

Comment: let me confirm it. ArrayList<? extends Damageable> means an ArrayList of any type that extends or implements the interface Damageable right?

Comment: Then how is that different from ArrayList<Damageable>? Does Java not know that I am passing an interface and that a concrete type behind it is needed?

Comment: Although a little scope creep, I wish this discussion also illustrated how to iterate the List in a for loop if all you know is the interface name. Hint:  it's _not_ `for( ? extends Damageable x : myList )`

Comment: It's amazing the search query I had to enter to find this Q/A. This is a very unintuitive side of Java. @user1944491 what is it then?

Comment: Is it not `for (Damageable d : myDamageables)`? Is that unintuitive?

Answer (score 2):

Try `ArrayList<? extends Damageable > _bodies`.

This says that you want an ArrayList consisting of a `Class` that extends (well implements) `Damageable`

Comment: What is the difference between ArrayList< <Class <? extends Damageable> > and ArrayList<? extends Damageable >?

Comment: I may be wrong here, but I think nothing. The one you have put specifies that it must be a Class, and extend/implement Damageable, but of course it has to be a class anyway (again I think). This is approaching the limits of my Generics knowledge though. Does your one compile?

Comment: ArrayList< <Class <? extends Damageable> > wasn't workable because doing this wont let me call methods that have been declared in the interface.

Comment: @wirate I think what you're thinking is correct in your first comment on this answer, however, what you typed won't compile.  `ArrayList<Class <? extends Damageable>>` (note the number of opening angle brackets) *will* compile, but then you'll have a list of `Class` objects rather than a list of `Damagable` objects.

Answer (score 2):

Others will no doubt point out the technical solutions from the Java syntax perspective.

I'm just going to mention a few design issues that you should perhaps consider:

- Your BaseObject implements Damageable. That means all BaseObjects are Damageable. Why not then just make a `CollisionManager(ArrayList<BaseObject>)`? Unless you are going to use Damageable elsewhere (i.e. there are things which are Damageable but are not BaseObjects) then it seems like an unnecessary abstraction.
- Usually for collision detection in a game / simulation you would want to use a spatial data structure for collision detection (e.g. Octree, Quadtree or AABB tree) rather than an ArrayList. Searching for collisions in an ArrayList is an O(n^2) algorithm. This will become a big issue if you have a lot of live objects.
- Damageable seems like a bad name, since the functionality relates to collision detection rather than damage - wouldn't Collidable be better?

Comment: In fact I did what you suggested in point 1. I was just being cautious.

Point 2: Box2D is detecting collisions and I just have to call a method on this type when a collision is detected

Point 3: There are objects in my situation that collide but are never damaged